# Microsoft.XMLDOM js question

Tags: javascript, xml

Is it possible to check if loaded with **xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlData);** xml string is invalid? For example if there is missed closing bracket or a tag.

Comment: um, yes if it is valid, but I think you mean *invalid* where you say *valid*.

Comment: @epascarello you are right :) It is total mess in my head right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass a string to `loadXML` that isn't a well-formed XML document, the document object will be empty (no childNodes) and `xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode` will be set to something other than `0`. `xmlDoc.parseError.reason` will give you a user-readable error message.

If you want to test a snippet and not a full document, wrap it in `<x>`...`</x>` tags so that the parser will only see one root element.

(There are a few reasons that MSXML might fail to parse a document other than it being non-well-formed. For example an external DTD subset or entity might not be network-reachable, or the DTD might use features MSXML doesn't support. You can't use MSXML to parse XHTML documents with their DTD for this reason. But if DTD-cruft isn't involved, a parser failure means the input wasn't well-formed.)

Comment: 10x @bobince I didn't see you answer :)

Answer (score 0):

All info about parse errors is hidden in "**xmlDoc.parseError**"